# Task Parallel Library - Task.Delay() usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am after some explanation of what's going on.

```
//VERSION: Async
private async void DoWorkAsync()
{
    Stopwatch stpWatch = new Stopwatch();
    _logger.WriteToLog("Doing some work...etc + ThreadID=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    stpWatch.Start();

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    stpWatch.Stop();
    _logger.WriteToLog("Work finished on ThreadID=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " ElapsedTime:" + stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Called as follows:

```
//loop 10 times
Parallel.For(1, 11, p => DoWorkAsync());
```

So far so good. The tasks do get delayed by approx 5 seconds as expected. (although the Parallel.For loop completes before, as expected).

However if i write the sync version of the above method:

```
//VERSION: Synchronous
private void DoWork()
{
        Stopwatch stpWatch = new Stopwatch();
        _logger.WriteToLog("Doing some work...etc + ThreadID=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        stpWatch.Start();

        Task.Delay(5000);

        stpWatch.Stop();
        _logger.WriteToLog("Work finished on ThreadID=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " ElapsedTime:" + stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

i.e. i removed the async/await keywords, and call similarly with

```
Parallel.For(1, 11, p => DoWork());
```

, there is no 5 secs delay as before and tasks complete almost immediately (as verified by my log file).

The Task.Delay statement seems to have no effect in the latter case, can i not use it without await keyword?

Hoping some TPL guru is able to explain what's going on please!

Comment: Maybe you could be interested in taking a look to the BackgroundWorker Class in Net 4.5  It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: I know all about the BackgroundWorker class since NET 2.0! the reason i am looking at TPL is because it's supposed to be the sexy new way of doing things recommended by M$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Task.Delay statement seems to have no effect in the latter case, can i not use it without await keyword?

Well you can't use it without doing *something* with the result. `Task.Delay` just returns a task that will complete later on. That's all it does. It doesn't - in itself - "do" anything to the current thread. Using `await` then schedules a callback to execute the rest of the async method when that task has completed, and returns control to the caller after scheduling the callback.

If you're looking for the synchronous equivalent of `Task.Delay`, that's basically `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: thanks Jon, got it! since it returns a Task t, i can in effect do t.Wait() which indeed makes the current thread wait. I just tested this and behaves exactly like Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @joedotnot: Yes, that will work too - but using `Thread.Sleep` would make it clearer that you're not *trying* to do anything asynchronous. Using `Result` and `Wait()` on tasks that aren't completed is usually a bad idea in asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you don't await the delay anymore, the processing just continues. In fact you don't have a delay anymore that way.

You need to replace the task.delay with a Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Task.Delay() creates a task that completes after the given time. You just created a task, and that completes very fast.

Comment: well the point is it has no effect on the current thread, unless we make it t.Wait(). See my comment to Jon's answer above.

Comment: Yes! The name of the static method Delay() is somewhat counterintuitive, as it really returns immediately after creatíng another task that is waiting a specific time ( see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx). One would think it´s a TPL pendant of Thread.Sleep, but it is indeed not!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
```

This is because you need to wait for the task to complete before continuing.